# click event on $root view model not working

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

i try to use nested loop with knockout js
this is my code:

```
self.MachineGroups = ko.observableArray();
$.each(mdl.MachineGroups, function (key, val) {
    self.MachineGroups.push(
        {
            "Index": key,
            "MachineGroupId": val.MachineGroupId,
            "MachineGroupName": val.MachineGroupName + val.ClientName,
            "ClientName": val.ClientName,
            "Machines": val.Machines,
            "hrefAttr": "#collapse_3_" + key,
            "idAttr": "collapse_3_" + key
        });
});

self.FindMachineData = function (data, event) {
    alert("Aaaa");
}
```

then this is my html to call knockout binding:

```
div class="col-xs-12" data-bind="foreach: MachineGroups">
            <div class="vastable togglesetup" data-bind="attr:{Id : 'machine-'+ idAttr}">
                <div class="tablename accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="text : MachineGroupName, attr:{ href :  hrefAttr}"></div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" data-bind="attr: { id : idAttr }">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <!--ko ifnot: $parent.LogedInUserTypeId() == 1 || $parent.LogedInUserTypeId() == 2-->
                            <!--ko if: $parent.AuthenticateToRegisterNewMachine-->
                            <div class="tablemenubar">
                                <div class="btn btn-sm cyanoutline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit"
                                     data-bind="click: $parent.RegisterNewMachine">Register New Machine</div>
                            </div>
                            <!--/ko-->
                            <!--/ko-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table table-foo">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Machine Name</th>
                                <th data-breakpoints="xs sm">Location</th>
                                <th data-breakpoints="xs sm">Last Detection</th>
                                <th>Machine Status</th>
                                <th>Expiry Date</th>
                                <th data-breakpoints="xs">Action</th>
                            </tr>

                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach : $data.Machines">
                            <tr>
                                <td data-bind="text : MachineName"></td>
                                <td data-bind="text : MachineLocation"> </td>
                                <td data-bind="text : LastDetectionTime"></td>
                                <td data-bind="attr:{id : MachineKey}">
                                    <!--ko if: MachineStatusId == 1-->
                                    <div class="status label-greenbg">Active</div>
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                    <!--ko if: MachineStatusId == 2-->
                                    <div class="status label-redbg">Inactive</div>
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                    <!--ko if: MachineStatusId == 3-->
                                    <div class="status label-darkgreybg">No Detection</div>
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                </td>
                                <td style="color:red; font-weight:bold;" data-bind="text : ExpiryDate"></td>


                                <td class="freecell">
                                    <p data-bind="text: console.log($root, $parent, $data)"></p>
                                    <!--ko ifnot: $root.LogedInUserTypeId == 1 || $root.LogedInUserTypeId == 2-->
                                        <!--ko if: $root.AuthenticateToEditMachine-->
                                            <button data-toggle="modal" href="#edit" class="btn cyan btn-sm" data-bind="click: $root.FindMachineData">Edit</button>
                                        <!--/ko-->
                                    <!--/ko-->
                                    <button data-toggle="modal" href="#detail" class="btn med-turquoise btn-sm" data-bind="click : $root.FindMachineDetail">Detail</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the problem is, when i try to access click function on root viewmodel, click event is not working.

can someone help me?

update:
i change the snippet into full html code. this is how i call the KO function.
i dont understand why i cannot perform click event

Comment: Is there any error when you click on the button?

Comment: no, nothing wrong. no error message

Comment: I guess this is just part of the code, but in this snippet you forget to applyBindings?

I've created a JSFiddle and it works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/tex59fej/1/

Comment: actually i used KO with asp.net Mvc and i apply KO binding on Cshtml file

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution finally. the problem happen because i combine knockout Js with Foo-table plugin. so the DOM was reset by foo-table. i remove the foo-table and problem disappear.

Thank you